# Searching an attribute in referenced documents with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a relationship, like this.

```
{
    _id : 1,
    "data" : "value"
}

{
   _id: 2,
   "otherData" : "Other value",
   "mainData: 1
}
```

As you can se, I have two documents and the second one has a reference to the first one.

It's any way to make a search like this??

```
Collection.find({"mainData.data" : "value"});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is more of a mongo question than a meteor question, please update your tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any coding you have to keep track of what you're doing.

```
Collection.find({"mainData.data" : "value"});
```

Both of those keys are undefined in your code and so `Collection.find` can't return anything. Also, your mainData key doesn't have a key called `data` so no matter what that will return `undefined.`

So what you would do is write something to get the `mainData` reference stored as a string.

```
let referenceCollection = Collection.find({'_id' : 2}); // 2 should really be a string
let referenceKey = referenceCollection.mainData; // this will return 1
Collection.find({'_id': referenceKey})
```

You could do a lot to make that better, but hopefully you see that your relationship only works when there's actual data to look for.